# Potential Bug - Default app crashes in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I am bootstrapping my React Native project with Expo 3.9.1 in macOS Catalina 10.15.1.

An error occurs when I try to create a project from scratch. Below are the steps to reproduce it

---

step 1: Create a project by running `expo init MyProject` in the terminal.

step 2: Select the 3rd item, "tab", with basic navigation

step 3: Run `cd MyProject`

step 4: Run `expo start`

step 5: Scan the QR code in Metro Bundler

step 6: Receive error

> Unable to resolve "./deprecations" from
>   "node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js"

---

Does anybody know what's going on and how to fix it? My app has crashed already and I haven't written a single line of code :/

Comment: Can u post ur react-navigation.js code

Comment: U can check this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4895

Comment: so i created another new project, and this time it worked! (got no errors) i'm even more confused now, since as far as i'm aware, i did not make any changes.